# sql server join for nonmatch

Tags: sql-server, join

[image]

what ever BU is present in table-2 that should be present in table-1 BU so write a query to find out the records available in table-2 whose BU is not available in table-1 BU.

Comment: select * from table-2 where BU not in (select distinct BU from table-1 )

Comment: here i write query like this but its not working properly.

Comment: What are you getting, then?

Comment: Define `but its not working properly`

Comment: Post the query you tried, and the error you got from it.

Comment: actually table-1 having 8526 records and table-2 having 1515 many records and after running my above query i get 1212 rows, but there are not non matched records.

Comment: We need specifics.  Show us the first few rows.

Comment: You say you have 8526 records in Table-1, but it looks like you have several duplicates. Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use left join where Table2 is left table so that you will get all the records from Table2 and matching records from Table1. And for those records from Table2 there is no match, result will shoe NULL entries for Table1. That's it-- that's what you are looking for --

```
SELECT T2.BU FROM Table2 T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 T1
ON T2.BU = T1.BU
WHERE T1.BU IS NULL
```

Comment: I am getting 1212 number of rows.

Comment: Try selecting DISTINCT T2.BU in above query

Comment: Great !! If it helped you solve your problem, would like to mark it as an answer please :)

Comment: how to filter 1:1 mapping

Comment: What you mean 1:1 mapping? If I understood it correctly - answer to your question is using INNER JOIN and use a WHERE clause for filtering.

Comment: 1:1 mapping means distinct BU of table-2 should same as distinct BU of table-1. if any extra BU is available in table-2 than it should be filter that record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145036/discussion-between-sachin-a-and-ajit-kumar).

Answer (score -1):

SELECT DISTINCT T2.BU FROM Table2 T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 T1
ON T2.BU = T1.BU
WHERE T1.BU IS NULL